# A problem of rarity

Tags: code-golf, math, number, array

Given a positive input \$n > 0\$, output the amout of two types based on their rarity. The two types are called \$A\$ and \$B\$, we know the followings:

- \$n\$ is a limited input and the maximum is \$nmax\$
- At the start \$B\$ is twice as rare as \$A\$
- As the presence of \$A\$ increade the rarity of \$B\$ decreases
- When \$n\$ = \$nmax\$, \$A\$ will be equal to \$B\$
- When \$n\$ is not \$nmax\$, \$A\$ cannot be equal to \$B\$
- The value of \$A\$ and \$B\$ cannot be decimal.

### Example

```
nmax = 10

n = 1, output = [1A, 0B]
n = 2, output = [2A, 0B]
n = 3, output = [2A, 1B]
n = 4, output = [3A, 1B]
n = 5, output = [3A, 2B]
n = 6, output = [4A, 2B]
n = 7, output = [4A, 3B]
n = 8, output = [5A, 3B]
n = 9, output = [5A, 4B]
n = 10, output = [5A, 5B]
```

Shortest code win.

Comment: So we have \$n = A+B\$ for any \$n\$ and \$nmax = 2A = 2B\$. Is that correct? If so, is \$nmax\$ guaranteed to be even?

Comment: Is \$nmax\$ another output? Or is it a constant which will always be \$10\$? May I output some values different to current one while it meets all requirements here? Or should I output exactly the same values as the example shown?

Comment: Say may I implement \$A_{nmax}(n)=\min\left\{n, nmax\right\}\$, \$B_{nmax}(n)=\max\left\{n - nmax, 0\right\}\$?

Comment: Also, what does _"at the start"_ exactly mean in the 2nd rule?

Comment: (@tsh I guess you meant "Is \$nmax\$ another input?")

Comment: Sorry it's my first question in this stack, i'll try to edit and be more clear.

Comment: If I read example correctly, output two numbers whose difference is 1 or 2 expect n=nmax?

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833) and nice first question! For future reference, we recommend using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) to get feedback on challenge ideas before posting them to main

Answer (score 6):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 25 bytes

```javascript
m=>n=>[a=n/2+(n<m)|0,n-a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcYxDoMwDAXQnVN4tJVCAyuYi1QMEZCqCL4rQF2gZw9M703hF7Z@/Xz3HDaMKWpatIW2r6B4Vo7RLHL6B/LQpWgrMUiprAnU3Po7zgkdGVFv2Gwei9neHLn0whCps3@6AA)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 24 bytes

```javascript
m=>n=>[b=n-(n<m)>>1,n-b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcYxDoMwDAXQnVN4tAWpyByci1QMQJOqCL4rQCyoZ0@Z3puHc9in7fM9HOyVStayaoTG56hwjG6VGH0DN/Yl20YMUvKBQN1te6euha6KaDLstqTHYm/O7FthiITqV/4)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 28 bytes

Expects `(nmax)(n)`. Returns `[B,A]`.

(This is based on my current understanding of the task.)

```javascript
m=>n=>[b=n/2-(n<m&~n)|0,n-b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcY9DoJAEAbQnlNMZWaCK4stDBcxFPwtwcA3BIyN6NVXqveezbvZu21aXw7WDzFoXLSCVo9Wkd0do1wuP8jhr3BtHYNtDFLKCwKVp/5Mmgp9EqLOsNs83GYbOXDuhSFSJN/4Bw)

Answer (score 3):

## Python, <s>266</s> 63 bytes

*And we're down to less than <s>half</s> <s>one-third</s> <s>one-quarter</s> <s>two-sevenths</s> one-quarter of my original*, so a lot less scuffed than anything I've put out, but it's a first answer:

```python
def a(b,c):
 m=(b<c)*(1-.5*(b%2))
 return int(b/2+m),int(b/2-m)
```

Takes advantage of the fact that \$\frac {a+1} {b+1} < \frac a b\$, if \$a > b\$: after that, it's just handling evens and a few exception cases.

-58 due to Wasif and a lambda of `str(int(n))`, plus dropping of whitespace.

-24 due to Wasif and the lambda function 2.

-14 by Wasif again and more cleaner conditionals.

-5 due to Wasif *again* by dropping the last else.

-15/-1 to Dominic van Essen and Lyxal respectively.

-3 from Wasif (making a return) and -6 from Dominic Van Essen again.

-39 from pxeger due to input semantics, taking us under halfway.

-9 from pxeger and -7 from Lyxal, taking us under 100, by returning a tuple instead of a list.

-2 from Dominic Van Essen, also managing to fix an error in the process

-14 from Dominic Van Essen again, with a nice simplification.

So far, total bytes saved:

- Wasif: 104
- pxeger: 48
- Dominic Van Essen: 47
- Lyxal: 8

Comment: This comment chain's gotten a bit long, but it's still a relevant discussion, so to reduce clutter on this post, I've [moved this conversation to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122913/discussion-on-answer-by-stackmeter-a-problem-of-rarity).

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
Se≠¹÷2+¹←=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9odXNr/21g4oKBwrnhuKP/U2XiiaDCucO3MivCueKGkD3///8xMA)

```
Se≠¹÷2+¹←=      # full program:
Se≠⁰÷2+⁰←=²⁰    # here with implicit final arguments added for clarity;
      +⁰        # add to n:
        ←       # one less than
         =²⁰    # 1 if n==m
                # (in other words, subtract 1 from n if n==m),
    ÷2          # now integer divide by 2,
Se              # and construct a 2-element list of the result together with
  ≠⁰            # the difference between itself and n
```